# how to update custom profile field data in buddypress

Tags: buddypress

I want to update custom profile field data in buddypress. I've been searching on google but still no luck. is there anyway to update it with a custom code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the default buddypress function

```
xprofile_set_field_data( $field, $user_id, $value, $is_required = false )
```

$fields = field id

$user_id = current login user id

$value = inserted value

$is_required = boolean

Here you have passed the specific insert fields data.

OR

You can insert your custom field data in usermeta table.
Like this:

```
update_user_meta($user_id, '$key', $_POST['post_value']);
```

$key = unique name of the fields